# Doubt about Lorentz transformations derivation: $y$ and $z$ axis

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Reading "Introduction to special relativity" by Resnick, I'm a bit confused about a detail in deriving Lorentz transformations.
Of course we consider the reference frames S and S' coinciding at $t=t'=0$, and we consider S' moving at speed $v$ relative to S.

He starts by saying that the most general formula is:
$$x'=a_{11}x+a_{12}y +a_{13}z +a_{14}t $$
And same for y', z' and t'.
He explains why the trasformations have to be linear, then he proceeds considering that the x axis and the x' axis always coincide, and this is true also for the xy plane and the x'y' plane, and for the xz plane and the x'z' plane.
From this considerations he concludes that the formulas for y' and z' have to be the following:
$$y'=a_{22}y$$
$$z'=a_{33}z$$
Up to this point everything seems clear to me.
In order to prove that $a_{22}$ and $a_{33}$ are both 1, he says: suppose we put a beam along the y axis, so that its extremities are at y=0 and y=1; we can assert that the beam lenghts equals 1 in the reference frame S. S' will see the beam lenght being $y'=a_{22}y=a_{22}$.
Now we put the beam at rest in S': if one of its extremities is at y'=0, then the other has to be at y'=1, because S and S' have to be equivalent for the relativity postulate. In this situation S will therefore measure the beam lenght being $y=\frac{1}{a_{22}}y'$.

The author concludes that the coefficient has to be 1, because S and S' must obtain the same measures. I don't understand why though. Of course on an intuitive level it is quite obvious that y=y', but I don't understand the conclusion given this reasoning: the important thing is that the beam's lenght is 1 when it is stationary relative to each frame of reference, and this is true even if the coefficient isn't 1. But S sees S' moving at speed v, while S' sees S moving at speed -v, so I don't understand why the measures of the beam in motion have to be the same.

It seems to me that we are assuming that, since the velocity is along the x-x' axis, then it can't interfere with the y and z axis, but do we have the right to make this assumption? And, in that case, couldn't we just immediately conclude that y=y' and z=z'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen a mathematical argument for the normal dimensions to velocity remaining unaffected, but I'll try to answer this.

Suppose that the factors $a_{22}$ and $\frac{1}{a_{22}}$ were not equal. Now, assume you are standing in $S$, and you measure the length of this beam along the y-axis. There are two outcomes:

(i)You measure the length of the beam to be unity, as in the first case.

(ii)You measure it as $\frac{1}{a_{22}}$

If you saw only one of these outcomes, it would mean that you can say which reference frame is moving, or is at rest. But, this is a violation of the first postulate of relativity, which says that all inertial frames are equivalent, and there is no absolute motion, i.e., no states of motion have anything special about them. So, the only way out is if both these events occur together, implying $a_{22}=1$. The same argument can be used for $S'$ as well, to arrive at the same conclusion, and that $a_{22} = \frac{1}{a_{22}}$

**Edit:**  As an answer to your comment, the same argument should work: say, $a_{22}$ and $\frac{1}{a_{22}}$ were not equal. Now, instead of the two events I mentioned above, take the events as the length observed from $S'$ and $S$ respectively, and we get the above-mentioned factors. But, if they were different, then also we would be able to predict absolute motion, just like the logic in the above paragraph. This forces us to conclude that the two factors are in fact equal.

Comment: Thank you. In the book though the author reaches the conclusion that $a_{22}=1$ because S and S' need to obtain the same measures for the beam (he explicitly concludes that we want $a_{22}=\frac{1}{a_{22}}$), while it appears to me that your argument is that $\frac{1}{a_{22}}=1$ and $a_{22}=1$, so that an observer in S, always sees the lenght of the beam to be unity. I understood your explanation, but it follows a different idea than the one in the book right? Or are they somehow equal? I'm just trying to understand if it it correct to assume that S and S' have to measure the same lenght.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I understood your explanation but now that I thought about it deeper I am confused again. Suppose S measures the lenght to be $\frac{1}{a_{22}}$: according to S, S' is moving and so is the beam. Yet, from the point of view of S' the beam is at rest relative to itself, in fact it measures the length to be 1, and it still sees S moving at speed -v. On the other hand, if the beam is at rest relative to S, S measures its length to be 1, and it sees S' moving at speed v; meanwhile, S' sees S, and therefore the beam, moving at speed -v, and it measures the lenght to be $a_{22}$.

Comment: So, I don't understand how from this we can conclude that S (or S') is absolutely at rest: can't we interprete both situations with S and S' moving relatively to each other?

Comment: The postulate says all inertial frames are equivalent. So if one is in a frame, and according to him he's at rest, if he encounters a similar situation elsewhere, there's nothing he can do to distinguish between the frames. So if he measures a length for the beam(at rest rel. to him), while 'being at rest' in a frame, the length should be the same in any other similar situation, else the frames won't be equivalent. I think I should've emphasized this non-equivalence of frames, rather than the absolute motion of frames. Your line of thought seems fine.

Comment: And, the non-equivalence of reference frames would mean that one can perform an experiment, such as measuring the beam length in this case, that would clearly indicate one of the frames to be in motion.